# java socket programming to send and receive file between two machines

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to communicate between two machines using socket programming.

What I basically need is both machines should be able to send and receive files. The code I am pasting below is not showing any error but the server side program seems to be running indefinitely, i.e., it is not terminating. It got stuck on the line marked with comment stuck here.

In this code, initially, server is sending the file named "file.txt" and client is receiving it and saving the file with name "copy.txt". Later client is sending a file named "file2.txt" and server is receiving and saving it with name "copy2.txt".

Can someone please tell me the error and suggest some improvements?

```
//server side code

import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 
public class server 
{ 
public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException 
{ 

    //sending file started
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(16167);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
    System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket); 
    File transferFile = new File ("/Users/abhishek/desktop/file.txt"); 
    byte [] bytearray = new byte [(int)transferFile.length()]; 
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile); 
    BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin); 
    bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream(); 
    System.out.println("Sending Files..."); 
    os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
    os.flush(); 
    System.out.println("File transfer complete"); 
    //socket.close();
    //sending comleted

    //receiving file started
    int filesize=1022386; 
    int bytesRead=0; 
    int currentTot = 0;  
    byte [] bytearray1 = new byte [filesize]; 

    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream(); 

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/abhishek/desktop/copy2.txt"); 
    //fos.flush(); 
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); 
    //bos.flush(); 
    System.out.println("not moving ahead!!!");//program stucked here
    bytesRead = is.read(bytearray1,0,bytearray1.length); 
    currentTot = bytesRead; 
    System.out.println("current"+currentTot); 
    do 
    { 
        bytesRead = is.read(bytearray1, currentTot, (bytearray1.length-currentTot)); 
        if(bytesRead >= 0) 
            currentTot += bytesRead; 
        System.out.println("current"+currentTot); 
    } while(bytesRead > -1); 
    System.out.println("outside current"+currentTot);
    bos.write(bytearray1, 0 , currentTot); 
    bos.flush(); 
    //receiving complete
    System.out.println("Receving file completed"); 
    socket.close(); 

} 
}



//client side code
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 


 public class client 
{ 
    public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException 
    { 
        int filesize=1022386; 
        int bytesRead=0; 
        int currentTot = 0; 
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",16167); 
        byte [] bytearray = new byte [filesize]; 
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream(); 
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/abhishek/desktop/copy.txt"); 
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); 
        bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
        currentTot = bytesRead; 
        do 
        { 
            bytesRead = is.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length-currentTot)); 
            if(bytesRead >= 0) 
                currentTot += bytesRead; 
        } while(bytesRead > -1); 
        System.out.println("current"+currentTot);
        bos.write(bytearray, 0 , currentTot); 
        bos.flush(); 
        bos.close(); 
        System.out.println("receiving first file completed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

        //sending file
        System.out.println("sending second file started!");
        File transferFile = new File ("/Users/abhishek/desktop/file2.txt"); 
        byte [] bytearray2 = new byte [(int)transferFile.length()]; 
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile); 
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin); 
        bin.read(bytearray2,0,bytearray2.length); 
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        os.flush();
        os.write(bytearray2,0,bytearray2.length); 
        os.flush();
        System.out.println("sending second file completed!");
        //sending complete


        socket.close();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the `System.out.println("not moving ahead!!!");//program stucked here` line actually execute? if so, then the problem is that the InputStream.read() functions are blobking functions; they will stop execution of the program ("block") until they are able to complete.

From the [JavaDoc for InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)):

> Reads up to len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer.
>   **This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.**

Since you aren't getting an exception, this means that when you call .read(), there is no data available to be read, and you program sits around waiting for data to read (that never arrives). You should check that your client program is actually sending the data in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that line is getting executed and i am sure it stuck at read() as there is no data available. But, I am sending data from client(you can check client program). But, I think the client is not finishing reading data of the first file(a file named "copy.txt" do get created but there is no data in it). So as the client is not completing its reading part of first file, there is no way it can send data for second file. So, how can I evade this situation?

Answer (score -1):

I'd bet

`bytesRead = is.read(bytearray1,0,bytearray1.length);`

is where you're really getting stuck. The problem normally if you are stuck here is that the other side of the communication has not sent any data, there's nothing to read, and your thread is stuck waiting for it to send.

on your client side, you call

`bos.close();`

after sending the first message. This is going to cause the socket to close as well, which will throw an IOException on your server end, and because you are not catching the IOException, your server program will just exit.

How much socket experience do you have? If you are just beginning with sockets, you might want to check out the extensions I wrote around this, starting with [ServerSocketEx](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/ServerSocketEx.java) and [DataFetcher](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java).

Comment: This feels like it should go into a comment.

Comment: @StackOverflowException I have updated this to answer the question asked, and to include this proposed advise.

Comment: Yes, that is where I am getting stuck. I am doing socket programming for the first time, so can you please tell any way that I can avoid this situation. Also, do read my comment on @Nekojimi reply below for better understanding of my problem.

Comment: @StackOverflowException Just updated my answer. Your problem is on the client side calling bos.close()

Comment: @user3245573: He meant you.

Comment: Well, I put the statement bos.close() in comment and executed and still nothing changed. It stuck at the same point as earlier.

Comment: That read() method will not throw an IOException when the peer closes the connection. It will return -1.